# iPhone center activity indicator regardless of screen orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How can I center an activity indicator programmatically regardless of screen orientation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting the `center` property of your activity view, like this:

```
 activity.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2);
```

---

In `viewDidLoad`, register for notifications for the device rotation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(didRotate:)
        name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

and implement `didRotate:`

```
-(void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {   
   if (activity) {
    activity.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it still going to be centered when I rotate the screen? thanks

Comment: Nope, you'll have to center it again as soon as it registers that it's turned.  So basically just center it again when you receive the rotation notification.  And welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: how and where do I make it re-center? i'm starting to like this place

Comment: I'll add to my answer.  Please let me know if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD 
Which is a great library for doing all kinds of "Loading" screens.